# Search site for npm modules that I forgot the name

Tags: javascript, node.js

I used to enter a very good search site for npm packages that I unfortunately forgot the name. This was the best package information site for npm that I knew. Not only was very complete with lots of details about the package, project activity, download numbers, popularity rating, as it even showed code examples, alternative packages and other info. I remember it has a dark theme and is very beautiful almost like a game design.

I'm aware of this question in SO: [How to find search/find npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568512/how-to-find-search-find-npm-packages)

But it's none of those. It's also much better than any of it.

Anyone know which site is this ? I searched a lot but can't find it again.

Comment: Please note that website recommendations are off-topic here (see: [Can I ask for recommended websites?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/191/185)). There's currently no other SE site covering this topic either, so you need to look for other resources (e.g. forums) for that.

Comment: @Izzy sorry didn't knew that. But as I read the link you sent me, in this case I think Openbase can be classified as a webapp as far as the criterias of Angelo Fuchs's answer are concerned. Maybe you would like to re-read them ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Folks at Reddit's /npm were quick to answer that one. It's [Openbase](https://openbase.com/)